# Will buying classes require a data connection to play?

Tags: android, puzzle-quest-2

I downloaded Puzzle Quest 2 for Android, and have been able to play the game in airplane mode just fine, but I have not yet paid to unlock any classes. Once I unlock classes, will I be able to continue to play in airplane mode, or will the game require me to have a data connection to verify my purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to purchase the full class unlock. I was able to switch my phone to airplane mode and was still able to play the game as normal.